# Que signifie "porteur de souffle" ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, définition

J'ai essayé de comprendre ce qu'on entend par cette expression : je ne trouve pas de bonnes explications.

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec la réponse donnée [ici](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/french-to-english/poetry-literature/7133258-porteurs-de-souffle.html) à Proz.com : merci de ne pas la citer comme "autorité" : je cherche avant tout à connaître les vues personnelles des francophones.

J'ai une théorie que cette expression pourrait en fait avoir une signification  assez proche de l'expression anglaise "force of nature", qui dans une de ses significations est un terme qui qualifie une personne, pour signifier quelqu'un avec beaucoup d'énergie et une personnalité forte.

Je remarque qu'on applique parfois ce terme "porteur de souffle" à des prophètes dans les fois abrahamiques. Mais, en cherchant j'ai découvert que quelqu'un a décrit l'écrivain maronite Khalil Gibran comme un "porteur de souffle *spirituel*". Ce qui impliquerait que la spiritualité n'est pas forcément implicite dans ce terme.

**Exemples**

"Véritable somme biographique, Khalil Gibran rend compte de cette trajectoire fulgurante.  Nul autre que Jean-Pierre Dahdah, traducteur de Gibran et libanais comme lui, pouvait nous faire connaître aussi intiment ce **"porteur de souffle spirituel"** qui sut repousser les frontières de la conscience et révéler nombre des secrets de l'âme humaine."
[lien](https://lapetitebouquinerie.com/boutique/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=12134&tag=Biographie&sort=p.price&order=ASC&page=5&limit=75)

"Gabriel Mwènè Okoundji a repris un épisode de son histoire : il est né au Congo (Brazzaville), « la terre des panthères ». Ses lointains ancêtres sont issus du royaume de Mwènè Motapa (souvent écrit par déformation : Monomotapa), dont la capitale était située sur les territoires de l’actuel Zimbabwé (nom qui signifie « la maison en pierre »). Dans ce royaume qui a existé du vie au xve siècle, est née la tradition de choisir et de nommer des mwènè, ces **porteurs de souffle** garants de la paix et de la spiritualité d’un peuple. C’est une autorité symbolique. Le père de Gabriel était lui même mwènè."
[lien](https://www.tupeuxsavoir.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Mensuel127.pdf)

ou bien, à propos d'un metteur en scène français qui a mis sur scène un spectacle au nom de "La Légende des Porteurs de Souffle" :
*"Un vrai **porteur de souffle** ..."* ([lien](https://www.transboreal.fr/horizons.php?horid=60)) et le texte semble raconter une initiative et une tournée qui auraient été "ardues".

Comment: L'expression n'étant pas courante, il serait utile de la contextualiser dans un extrait de texte ou une phrase.

Comment: Philippe Fenwick ne serait peut-être pas d'accord pour dire que la première tournée de sa pièce ait été ardue (pourquoi ce jugement de "prétendument" ?) et ça n'a rien à voir avec le fait qu'il soit qualifié de porteur de souffle.

Comment: Dans "porteur de souffle", *souffle* est utilisé dans le sens de "mouvement, élan d'exaltation, d'aspiration profonde, d'inspiration (un souffle de liberté). A partir des exemples trouvés avec [ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22porteur%20de%20souffle%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1983,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_fr), on voit que très souvent, la spiritualité est présente. Mais, dans une phrase comme "*Les élections vont permettre , avec une nouvelle chambre , de former un gouvernement porteur de souffle nouveau*",  tout les francophones comprendront qu'un nouvel élan politique est espéré.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille voir là  une expression toute faite, encore moins en lien spécifique avec la religion. Pour moi un porteur de souffle, c'est tout simplement quelqu'un qui porte un souffle. Bien sûr, le souffle est d'ordre spirituel mais il y a d'autres formes de spiritualité que la religion.

Qu'est que le **souffle** ? Voir, entre autres, le TLFi (D) :

> − Au fig. [Le souffle en tant qu'influence immatérielle qui inspire un créateur; à propos d'un artiste, d'un écrivain, d'un homme de science ou de son œuvre] Énergie créatrice, richesse d'inspiration. Le souffle du génie; le souffle d'un écrivain.

On parle parfois de certains artistes comme des « porteurs de souffle », c'est à dire qu'ils portent en eux une énergie créatrice, une inspiration et qu'ils la transmettent.

**Porter** (TLi II A b) :

> Se déplacer pour transmettre à quelqu'un.

– [Philippe Fenwick](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Fenwick) cité dans la question et auteur de la pièce *La légende des Porteurs de souffle* est décrit comme un porteur de souffle parce que :

> Comme tous les vrais poètes, il vit sa passion, il la chante, la met en mouvement, s’en sert comme d’un levier pour soulever la chape de passivité et de résignation. ([→](https://www.transboreal.fr/horizons.php?horid=60))

La pièce s'appelle *La Légende des Porteurs* de souffle parce que les porteurs de souffle sont le sujet de sa pièce, et le premier paragraphe décrit sa vision des porteurs de souffle.

– Le spectacle des Baladins du miroir [*La Porteuse de Souffle*](https://lesbaladinsdumiroir.be/spectacle/la-porteuse-de-souffle/) :

> raconte ces moments de vie qui engagent soudain les individus à se questionner, à changer de cap, à repartir à zéro ou simplement à reprendre courage et retrouver l’ardeur de vivre. Sans revendications sociales ou politiques, au travers d’une dramaturgie simple, l’histoire dépeint ces instants où chaque personnage, quelle que soit sa condition sociale, a un problème à résoudre, un rêve à poursuivre.

Donc le porteur de souffle c'est celui qui veut transmettre la vision et l'inspiration qu'il porte en lui, quelles que soit l'ordre de cette inspiration.

---

*A [force of nature](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/force_of_nature)* en français c'est une [force de la nature](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/force_de_la_nature). Le terme implique une force physique, porter un souffle est uniquement d'ordre spirituel et aucun besoin de force physique pour ça.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Au fait "force of nature" en anglais n'implique pas une force physique : il y a un rien ironique dans l'expression. Cela peut suggérer un individu un peu difficilement tolérable, mais qui est capable d'accomplir quelque chose. Etant Anglais, je ne sais pas si l'expression française soit 100 % identique en terme de connotations.